# Bookmark that takes the displaying URL and adds additional string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarks

This is what I need to accomplish.
Say I go to example.com on Chrome browser. I have a certain bookmark on my browser, on which when I click it automatically takes the `example.com` URL and adds a certain string, for example `cache:` and when I click that bookmark it will take me to `cache:example.com`
When I go to `example2.com` and click on the bookmark again, it will take me to `cache:example2.com`
Is there a Javascript code or else that can make this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add some javascript to change the window.location.href attribute.

The following will help

```
javascript:(
    function(){
        f='cache:'+window.location.href;
        if(!window.open(f))
            location.href=f;
    }
)()
```

You can change and set the href to whatever you want

You have to add this javascript to an anchor tag so that when the link is dragged and dropped in a browser's bookmarklet bar, it get added. So the link will be like this:

```
<a title="GotoCache" href="javascript:(function(){f='cache:'+window.location.href;if(!window.open(f))location.href=f;})()">Goto Cache</a>
```

Add this link in a page and you are set :)

Comment: This works almost great. I added the javascript to a bookmark in Chrome. But I still need to press Enter so that the cached website load. how can I make the page load automatically upon clicking on bookmark? Thanks

Comment: That is because your bookmarklet is trying to access the user's browser cache and unless the user gives explicit permission, he has to press enter. This will work if the url that you are opening is for something else like adding extra arguments or altering the url. The problem you are facing is because you are trying to access the cache.

Comment: Is there a way to open this bookmark in the existing window instead of a new tab?